# Are Java Basics necessary for AnyLogic?

Tags: java, anylogic

Can I create a process modeling simulation without java knowledge? So does it work to use only the process modeling library to create a complex model without using functions?

Comment: have you checked the AnyLogic documentation?

Comment: From [tag:anylogic] *AnyLogic allows businesses, researchers, and public policy makers to evaluate decisions before they're implemented in practice* I would dearly love to know what Java knowledge you think public policy makers have.

Comment: In the example models like the distribution center model I see the usage of complex java functions. So my question was if I can create such a model without this functions and only with the different processes of the library. So apparently yes?

Comment: I want you to think about hammers. Can I use a hammer to build something basic? I see hammers being used to build skyscrapers. But I just want to build a picture frame. I take it you can use a hammer to build a picture frame? What about a sledge hammer? And what about powder actuated nail guns? Yes... you could use it to make a picture frame. I wouldn't. But you could. Probably not terribly helpful, but then anylogic just looks like a hammer to me.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's possible to create models without using any JAVA at all, you will soon discover that you end up being extremely limited and you will not be able to do anything complex.
Without JAVA you will be able to do:

- Any kind of complex system dynamics model (you don't need java at all for this).
- Toy level process flows using discrete events.
- Probably almost nothing using Agent-Based.
- Basic level experiments.

Now you have a few libraries in AnyLogic as well and you can do a lot with them as well... but you won't be able to reach a level higher than basic with any of them.

This is true for any simulation package, not only AnyLogic... even Arena you need to know Visual Basic or you won't get very far.